# How to get the Chinese name of a security in blpapi?

Tags: java, bloomberg, blpapi

I have a **BDP** function that looks like this.

```
BDP("Glen Ln Equity","NAME_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED")
```

It is to update the Chinese name of a security.

I have to translate it to Java blpapi but I am not sure how.

Since this is a BDP function, I think I should use Reference Data Request but you can only specify the ticker and field mnemonic when creating a Reference Data Request. I also know I can use override but to use an override, based on my understanding, I will need a fieldID so that I can set that fieldID's value to be `"NAME_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED"`.

However, I am not sure what fieldID to use.

What fieldID should I use for the override?

Also, where can I find a list of fieldIDs that can set for overrides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine with a reference data request - you don't need to override anything here:

```
Element security = request.getElement("securities");
security.appendValue("GLEN LN Equity");

Element field = request.getElement("fields");
field.appendValue("NAME_CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED ");
```